# Encountering errors when writing a quicksort function in R using a partition function

Tags: r

I've been writing this quicksort function in R trying to incorporate a partition function I've created as well. However, I've been encountering bugs when comparing p and r. It keeps telling me my argument is of length 0, however, I thought I declared the p and r objects when I initially called the quicksort function.

```
partition <- function(input,p, r){
  pivot = input[r]
  while(p<r){
    while(input[p]<pivot) {p<-p+1}
    while(input[r]>pivot) {r<-r-1}
    if(input[p]==input[r]) {p<-p+1}
    else if (p<r){
      tmp <- input[p]
      input[p] = input[r]
      input[r] = tmp
    }
  }
 return(r)
}


quicksort<- function(input,p,r){

 if(p<r){
    j<- partition(input,p,r)
    input <- quicksort(input,p,j-1)
    input <- quicksort(input,j+1,r)

 }

}

input <- c(500,700,800,100,300,200,900,400,1000,600)
print("Input:")
print(input)
quicksort(input,1,10)
print("Output:")
print(input)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in question is caused because input[p] is of length zero. Why? Because in this instance input is NULL. input isn't NULL for the first few goes, so what would make it NULL?

Your quicksort function is designed to take an input, change it (if `p<r`), and then output it. *But*, you've left out the output step. If `p<r` then this is taken care of implicitly by the last `input <- ...` line, but if not then the function doesn't do anything and just returns NULL.

The output from one call to quicksort is the input to the next, and so this NULL propagates and breaks the next call.

Recursive functions are beautiful but often frustrating to debug. I recommend liberally sprinkling print() statements around while you're still developing it so you can see what it's doing more easily.